# How do I check for a NULL value when using JSPs GET method?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, get

When a post method is submitted, a JSP page shows the result in fields in the next page. How can I red mark those fields who gets null value in the 2nd page?

Comment: how are you displaying the values in the next page?

Comment: <c:forEach var="iterator" items="${dataList}" varStatus="idx">
<table class="tableForm">
<tbody>
 <tr>
   <th>Name : </th>
  <td> <c:outvalue="${iterator.name}"/>  </td>             </c:forEach>
</tbody>
</table>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the forEach loop you can write,

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test='${iterator.name eq ''}'>
        <td style='background-color:red;'> <c:outvalue="${iterator.name}"/> </td>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <td> <c:outvalue="${iterator.name}"/> </td>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

As you can see when the value will be null you can set the background color of that cell to red and when it returns some value you can display it the way you were doing it before.